# How do I use insert into from in sql when I need to insert from 2 tables joined together and another table

Tags: sql, oracle

```
INSERT INTO reserve ( 
    branch_code, 
    bc_id, 
    reserve_date_time_placed, 
    bor_no )
SELECT b.branch_code, 
       c.bc_id, 
       TO_DATE('2018-09-20, 4:00 P.M.', 'YYYY-MM-DD, HH:MI P.M.'), 
       w.bor_no FROM borrower w
FROM borrower w, book_copy c
     JOIN branch b on c.branch_code = b.branch_code
WHERE b.branch_contact_no = '8888888883'
AND c.book_call_no = '005.74 C822D 2018'
AND w.fname = 'Ada';
```

I tried to insert into the reserve table the bor_no from borrower table individually, and other information from book_copy table joined with branch table.

So I think to better explain my question, I try to insert into reserve table from (book_copy joined with branch) and (borrower). But borrower and book_copy has no relationship.

```
borrower table is created like below.

    CREATE TABLE borrower (
    bor_no         NUMBER(6) NOT NULL,
    bor_fname      VARCHAR2(59) NOT NULL,
    bor_lname      VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
    bor_street     VARCHAR2(80) NOT NULL,
    bor_suburb     VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
    bor_postcode   CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
    branch_code    NUMBER(2) NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: I assume you are using Oracle based on the `varchar2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One error is your multiple `FROM` clauses.  Try writing the query like this:

```
INSERT INTO reserve (branch_code, bc_id, reserve_date_time_placed, bor_no )
    SELECT b.branch_code, bc.bc_id, 
           TO_DATE('2018-09-20, 4:00 P.M.', 'YYYY-MM-DD, HH:MI P.M.'), 
           w.bor_no 
    FROM book_copy bc JOIN
         branch b 
         ON bc.branch_code = b.branch_code JOIN
         borrower w
         ON w.fname = 'Ada'
    WHERE b.branch_contact_no = '8888888883' AND
          bc.book_call_no = '005.74 C822D 2018';
```

Note that this uses proper `JOIN` syntax for *all* `JOIN`s.  There is no comma in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: I alter the code as per above and get an error: ORA-00904: "W"."FNAME": invalid identifier. because table borrower is separate from other tables, there's no relationship between them. Can we use join in this case to join them?

Comment: @Barney_su . . . That is the column reference you use in *your* query.  I do not know if `borrower` has a column named `fname`, but your code suggests it does.  And yes, this condition is valid in an `on` clause.  You can also use `cross join` and put the condition in the `where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

**Take care that you have "from borower" twice in you example.**

After that you could just use insert into ... select ...

```
INSERT INTO reserve ( 
branch_code, 
bc_id, 
reserve_date_time_placed, 
bor_no ) 
SELECT b.branch_code, 
       c.bc_id, 
       TO_DATE('2018-09-20, 4:00 P.M.', 'YYYY-MM-DD, HH:MI P.M.'), 
       w.bor_no 
FROM  book_copy c
     JOIN branch b on c.branch_code = b.branch_code
     JOIN bororwer w on c ..... = w. .... 
WHERE b.branch_contact_no = '8888888883'
AND c.book_call_no = '005.74 C822D 2018'
AND w.fname = 'Ada';
```

What is your error?

EDIT: 
You can do the insert only from book_Copy and branch like that:

```
INSERT INTO reserve ( 
branch_code, 
bc_id, 
reserve_date_time_placed, 
bor_no ) 
SELECT b.branch_code, 
       c.bc_id, 
       TO_DATE('2018-09-20, 4:00 P.M.', 'YYYY-MM-DD, HH:MI P.M.'), 
       w.bor_no 
FROM  book_copy c
     JOIN branch b on c.branch_code = b.branch_code
      WHERE b.branch_contact_no = '8888888883'
AND c.book_call_no = '005.74 C822D 2018'
```

After that get borrower_id into a variable

```
select @borower_id from borrower where fname = 'Ada'
```

and then update reserve:

```
update reserve set borrower_id = @borrower_id 
where book_call_no = .... and branch_contact = .. ...
```

Comment: I got SQL Error: ORA-00904: "W"."FNAME": invalid identifier from the code above.

Comment: Ok I edited my answer to put column names, but you should join book_copy with borower.

Comment: As table borrower is separate from other tables, there are no relationship between them. Can we use join in this case to join them?

Comment: pk in borrower table is not in book_copy table.

Comment: No, if you want to include in you query you MUST have a relationship.

Comment: bor_no is pk in borrower and fk in reserve table. bc_id is the pk in book_copy table and pfk in reserve table. So I think to better explain my question, I try to insert into reserve from (book_copy joined with branch) and (borrower). But borrower and book_copy has no relationship.

Comment: Then you should one inserta and one update after you should make 1. insert into reserve from book_copy joined branch. 2. update reserve from borower using 'Ada' to filter from borower.